# Call Java Cryptography Architecture (JCA) from PL/SQL

Tags: java, oracle, plsql

Is it possible to access (call) Java Cryptography Architecture (JCA) classes from PL/SQL? For example, when stored procedure are running.

P.S. The big task is to validate digital signature (RSA) in PL/SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, have you looked at the DBMS_CRYPTO package in Oracle?  If that supports the algorithm(s) you need, I would suggest using it instead of calling Java.

But yes, if necessary, you should be able to call JCA from PL/SQL.  It looks to me like this is part of the core JDK and therefore should be included in the Oracle built-in Java environment already, but even if that were not the case you could load the classes into the database yourself.  The only major limitation is that you can't utilize JNI within the database, but I think that's not relevant in this case.

If your question is more generally how to call Java from PL/SQL, then start with [the Oracle Java Developer manual.](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/java.102/b14187/toc.htm)  The chapter on Java Stored Procedures is primarily what you need.

Comment: Yes, but as I can understand DBMS_CRYPTO does not support RSA (PKCS#1).